# How to solve intermittent Ansible issues?

Tags: ansible

I am sure at some point or another someone must have faced a situation where one is unable to install a package via ansible but the same thing is easily done by logging into the machine and doing so. This is very intermittent but it is persistent. Why I say so? Because once in a while it might happen that a package refuses to get installed throuwing some error like

```
failed: [10.12.10.57] => {"failed": true, "parsed": false}
BECOME-SUCCESS-yqymkgrsndxbhkcnyfjgvzrxvoxpmads
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1461058305.77-7941776655744/apt", line 2258, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1461058305.77-7941776655744/apt", line 554, in main
    cache = apt.Cache()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 107, in __init__
    self.open(progress)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 151, in open
    self._cache = apt_pkg.Cache(progress)
SystemError: E:Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-updates_main_i18n_Translation-en (1), E:The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master
debug1: mux_client_request_session: master session id: 2
Shared connection to 10.12.10.57 closed.
```

You can run the play again and again but it won't go away, but once you get inside the machine and do something like `apt-get update` , it simply goes away even though the machine is already updated. This happens in like 1 out of the 100 cases , but it does occur, I am unable to figure out why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be the fact that you're trying to run your playbook too soon immediately after your EC2 instance is started? I have the feeling that some other client (say your system) is locking your apt directory. If this is the case, wait until the server is completely started. You can also take a look to `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log` to see what the box does when it's starting (you'll see some `apt-get` outputs there).

When it happens again, try to find if this is the reason by removing the lock files like:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
```

And run the playbook again. If it succeeds, it does point to that this is the problem. In addition, if you find that the problem is due to the playbook runs too soon, you might want to consider to add a delay like explained here: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/wait_for_module.html or any other kind of event catcher to determine if your system is ready to be used.